# Can you zip with the new ranges library?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

See: http://eel.is/c++draft/#ranges

Given two C++2a ranges (as in objects that conform to the ranges concept of the ranges library) a and b, of equal length, is there a way to zip them together such that:

```
for (const auto& [a,b] : zip(a,b))
```

does what you expect?  That is, it returns a range that has something destructurable binding pairs:

```
(a.begin(), b.begin())
(a.begin()+1, b.begin()+1)
(a.begin()+2, b.begin()+2)
...
(a.end()-1, b.end()-1)
```

Comment: _Zip_ what please?? Post a self contained question as required.

Comment: What do you expect?

Comment: You mean something like Python [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#zip)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As you can see, there is no `zip_view` currently in C++20 (as of this writing).

It was being proposed in [P1035R4](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1035r4.html) (along with a handful of other adapters), the previous version of which was favorable received in San Diego and seemed like it has a very reasonable chance of landing in C++20. There are open questions regarding proxy references, but I don't think that's specific to `zip`.

---

Those questions regarding proxy references ended up causing `zip` to get dropped from P1035 and it was not adopted for C++20. Instead, `zip` is being proposed for C++23 as part of [P2321](https://wg21.link/p2321) (which additionally includes a description of the kinds of proxy reference changes I mentioned).

Comment: Why is the example `for (auto xy = view::zip(x, y); auto [xi, yi] : xy)` and not `for (auto [xi, xi] : xy)` ?

Comment: @AndrewTomazos You mean why isn't it `for (auto [xi, yi] : view::zip(x, y))`? Just a matter of taste, the two are equivalent.

Comment: Barry maybe update the answer to say that planned standard is now C++23

Answer (score 0):

[ranges v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3)
niebler has already made public a library with a lazy zip and some more general forms also zip_view and others. Implemented as a header only library so you can read the code. With some nice examples of uses. 
In c++ zip will probably return a tuple when asked. and indexing into that tuple will give you the values.

Comment: Yes, `range-v3` is what `std` ranges in C++20 is based on... but it hasn't (yet) migrated `zip`.